# Need to increase the size of Radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am using MVC 3 with jQuery mobile. The buttons on my phone browser are too small. I have tried different properties, but nothing seems to be working. Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="radio">    
  @HTML.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ButtonLabel)
</div>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-role="radio">    
  @HTML.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ButtonLabel,true, new { @style = "margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);"})
</div>
```

True is the value for radiobutton. Ofcourse there is going to be 2nd radiobutton which will be having false value.or another way is you can create class with above css and apply that class to radiobutton like @class="class_radio". scale increase size of you radio button.

Hope it helps